# Mockito access the result of a method

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito

Is it possible to pass the result of a method as the return value of another mocked one?

I have something similar to:

```
Order savedOrder = orderDataService.save(order);
try{
    savedOrder = orderDataService.findById(savedOrder.getId());
} catch (SomeException e) {
...
}
```

and because I have some business logic in the save method, I wouldn't want to create a mocked result, but to gain access to it and use it also as a result for the find method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Spy` and partial mocking. In a general case, assuming a class like this:

```
public class MockedBean {
    public String mockedMethod() {
        return "should have been mocked!";
    }
    public String notMockedMethod() {
        return "should NOT have been mocked!";
    }
}
```

Yuu can do partial mocking like:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    MockedBean mb = new MockedBean();
    MockedBean spy = Mockito.spy(mb);
    when(spy.mockedMethod()).thenReturn("THE MOCKED VALUE");
    log.info("{}", spy.mockedMethod());
    log.info("{}", spy.notMockedMethod());
}
```

This would result into output like:

> 20:32:14.180 [main] INFO org.example.mockito.partialmock.PartialMock - THE MOCKED VALUE
>   20:32:14.183 [main] INFO org.example.mockito.partialmock.PartialMock - should NOT have been mocked!